# How to round off a floating point no. To two decimal points?

Tags: c

I have written a programs in which computer ask for a floating point no. From the user. For example if, i am entring 0.41, the ouput in printf is 0.409999999. How to resolve this error?

Comment: Read e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Pay close attention to the possibility to set the field width and more importantly the *precision*.

Comment: you did not show your printf code.

Comment: What platform are you on? 0.41 should be no problem even when scanf'd and stored as a float on a normal 32-bit system

Comment: Show the code that printed `0.409999999`

Comment: I am working on CS50 IDE platform

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. Use:

```
printf("%.2f", 0.409999999);
```

This will print 0.41

Answer (score 1):

- %f   (print as a floating point)
- %4f  (print as a floating point with a width of at least 4 wide)
- %.4f (print as a floating point with a precision of four characters after the decimal point)
- %3.2f    (print as a floating point at least 3 wide and a precision of   2)

Answer (score 0):

Most floating points datatypes are, by their nature, imprecise. They try to store real numbers (infinite precision) in a limited precision bit-vector. As such, it's possible the closest representation of 0.41 on your platform is 0.409999999.

You should read up on the IEEE754 floating point representation to get an idea what's kind of issue you hit there.

Comment: Detail: floating points data types are very precise, each finite value is exact.  It is the functions and operations that use these types that are the source of imprecision.  `double x = 0.41;`  `x` takes on an exact value - perhaps 0.409999999999999975575093458246556110680103302001953125, which does not equal 0.41.

Comment: @chux yeah, for what they're doing, they're quite precise. But they don't have unlimited precision. If 0.41 becomes 0.4099[...]999, then it's close to, but not precisely 0.41. A new developer coming from ints and starting  with floats the 1st time might not be aware of this; thus wondering what (s)he' doing wrong when (s)he's building a float from 0.41 and getting only something really close to that value... Of course if the OP is a software engineer with 5+ yrs of experience, that's a plain * question to ask. For a newbie, it's ok (so I gave a real answer instead of "omg, you should know")